# How many isometries of the (unit) 2-sphere are there?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, isometry

I had a homework problem that exhibited two Killing vector fields for the 2-sphere, asked me to find a third and then asked me if there are any more. I answered no because the Lie Algebra of the isometry group is 3-dimensional (we are only interested in smooth isometries here).

My question is, how could I have seen this without prior knowledge of $SO(3)$, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine there are several ways. Here's how I would do it:

The dimension of the isometry group $\mathfrak{I}(M,\mathrm{g})$ of a Riemannian $n$-manifold $(M,\mathrm{g})$ has an upper bound of $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Since $S^2$ with the usual Riemannian metric is complete, the Lie algebra of Killing vectors is isomorphic to the Lie algebra of the isometry group. Thus, we cannot have more than $\frac{2(2+1)}{2}=3$ linearly independent Killing vectors.

Comment: This is basically what I argued, albeit less carefully. Where did you get the upper bound from? And does this work with non-Riemannian (specifically Lorentzian) manifolds?

Comment: The isometry group can be considered as a subbundle of the orthonormal frame bundle, which has dimension $n+n(n-1)/2=n(n+1)/2$. I don't know if this works for non-Riemannian manifolds, since I know very little about the orthonormal frames of such structures.